# Merge data from 600+ Excel worksheets and 1 Google doc

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, merge, google-docs

I have around 30 Excel spreadsheets, each with 20+ worksheets. Each of these worksheets follows the same basic format, though there are slight differences. I also have a Google doc with sections that match each of the worksheets.

Somehow I need to merge the data from the spreadsheets and the Google doc into a single, searchable, editable document, which will become the new safe source, eliminating the need to maintain 600+ worksheets.

So far, the plan is to have an intern copy/paste from Excel into the appropriate section in the Google doc, but besides being akin to torture, I'm afraid this approach will take days.

Can anyone think of a way to automate at least some of this?

I've been thinking that if I could somehow take all of the Excel data and migrate it into either Microsoft Word or a Google Doc, that would be a good first step.

I have used Google Apps Script in the past and could probably figure out how to write a macro in Excel, but I can't wrap my head around how I would actually accomplish what I need to do.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I would try to merge everything to Access

Comment: If the `.xlsx` are in Drive, you can import them to a Google Sheet equivalent, and then use the Spreadsheet & Documents Services to collate data. If they are local and can't be placed on Drive / uploaded, then you'll need to utilize the Google Sheets API from your custom local program (written in VBA, C#, node.js, Java, etc.). There is not (yet) a Google Docs API - the only programmatic access to Google Docs is via Apps Script - so you would need to write an Apps Script webapp (or use the Apps Script API appropriately) to manage interactions with your Google Doc from your local program.

Comment: Do note that a Google sheet has a limit of 2M cells. Estimate whether 600 sheets can be contained within that limit in a single google sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to provide an update in case anyone else ever has a similar problem...

I ended up moving all of the existing spreadsheets to Google Drive and using Google Apps Script to iterate through the folder to get the name and id of each file and then iterate through all worksheets of each of those spreadsheets, copy all data from each sheet and append it to a new master spreadsheet.

I then migrated the existing Google Doc to a Google Sheet so I could sort.

After that I manually copied the applicable sections from this Google Sheet into the correct, corresponding section of the master spreadsheet. I'm sure someone smarter than me would have been able to script that last part as well, but I was having trouble figuring out the logic and decided to brute force the last step.